# Can ethics be a continuum

Tags: ethics, subjectivity, objectivity

Writing a paper for an introduction to philosophy course. I'm trying to argue that ethics are not simply objective or subjective, but somewhere in between, like a continuum.

What I'm trying to say, but I'm having trouble explaining. Is that actions or concepts are all relative to each other. While there might be an objective truth that murder is wrong for example, there are things worse than murder, and things not as bad as murder. So while we can say murder is bad, we can't say it is the "worst"

I believe this relies on human understanding as imperfect. We will never truly be able to grasp reality as it exists.

Comment: Hopefully relevant: [contrastivism in ethics](https://iep.utm.edu/ethics-and-contrastivism/).

Comment: Your idea for this paper if true would be ground breaking. I am not sure you can make a divide as you like at least in NORMATIVE ETHICS. OBJECTIVE is an absolute. An absolute cannot change value at any point in time. Subjective means there will be cases where x is true & x is false. This means subjective is contingent. Contingent means not 100 percent true. The other types of ethics are closer to Psychology not Philosophy such as utilitarianism and so on.

Comment: Your question could be improved by removing the poisoned well ("understanding is imperfect") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well and the stolen concept it introduces.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea#stolen_concept

Comment: Can you explain what your question is? I am assuming you are having trouble writing a part of this essay, but you never say where you are having trouble.